# How change button clicklistener outside activity in android?

Tags: java, android, dex, smali, dexclassloader

I have an apk that contains classes.dex. I dont't have apk source code. I have loaded an activity from dex file(LoginActivity) and implemented onClicklistener for button1 in LoginActivity. I succeeded to load dex file and started activity from dex file via this code:

```
DexClassLoader dex = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(), mAppContext.getCacheDir().getPath(), null, loader);    
toasterClass = dex.loadClass("com.example.myapplication.ui.login.LoginActivity");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),toasterClass);
setContentView(View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_login, null));
Button mAddTaskButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
mAddTaskButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog aldlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(gLoginActivity.this).create();
                aldlg.setTitle("Login");
                aldlg.setMessage("You pressed Login Button");
                aldlg.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                aldlg.show();
            }
        });
startActivity(intent);
```

but when I clicked button2, it didn't show alertdialog. I think android is preventing to change onClicklistener outside from activity. Is it correct?
Any help how to implement this?

Comment: In which class do you call to ` findViewById(R.id.button2)`  in your snippet (from your other Activity class )?

Comment: yes,I call findViewById(R.id.button2) in another Activity(MainActivity).

Comment: Sorry but based on your description I don't understand what you are actually trying to do. Especially how may apps and what dex files are involved is not quite clear. Please edit your question and describe in detail what you want to do and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use code:

```
Button mAddTaskButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2)
```

it means that you try to find view in your current Activity instance (same thing as `this.findViewById`)- not from `com.example.myapplication.ui.login.LoginActivity`

I have two ideas to solve your problem:

1. Using Application/Activity method [registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) ([link for activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) ). [This callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) has method [onActivityCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks#onActivityCreated(android.app.Activity,%20android.os.Bundle)) which provides instance of created activity. In this method you can get Activity's name by calling to `activity.getComponentName().getClassName()` (link to [getComponentName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getComponentName()) method and to [ComponentName class description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName) ). If activity provided by `onActivityCreated` method is `com.example.myapplication.ui.login.LoginActivity` then you can add OnClickListene to button like in your code snippet(just use reference to activity to get Button):

```
Button mAddTaskButton = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button2);
mAddTaskButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                      ...
            }
        });
```

Be careful with ActivityLifecycleCallback because it attaches to application life-cycle (not activity) and don't capture Activity's content from callback to avoid memory links.

2. Another solution - you can try to create "stub" activity with name com.example.myapplication.ui.login.LoginActivity then extend it like:
   `public class MyLoginActivity extends LoginActivity`. Then you can override MyLoginActivity's onCreate method and do what you want (I mean add your code for button onClick listener). But you don't need to build in this "stub" LoginActivity to application (apk), you should add it as compile only dependency. I don know how do it with a class but I know other solution: you can put LoginActivity to separate module or library(aar/jar) and add the library(module) as [compileOnly dependency to your gradle file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations)  ([like here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#kts))